# Nested association not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-6, model-associations

I have a nested association for a customer. The setup is like this:

- A customer has one address
- An address has a physical_address
- An address has a postal_addrsss

**Address model**

```rb
  belongs_to :customer, optional: true # Yes, optional
  
  has_one :physical_address, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :postal_address, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :physical_address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :postal_address
```

**Postal Address model**

```rb
# same for physical_address.rb
belongs_to :address
```

**Customer controller:**

```rb
def create
  @customer = current_user.customers.build(customer_params)

  if @customer.save
    return puts "customer saves"
  end

  puts @customer.errors.messages
  #redirect_to new_customer_path
  render :new
end

private
  def customer_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(
      address_attributes: address_params
    )
  end

  def address_params
    return ([
      postal_address_attributes: shared_address_params,
      #physical_address_attributes: shared_address_params
    ])
  end

  def shared_address_params
    params.fetch(:customer).fetch("address").fetch("postal_address").permit(
      :street, etc...
    )
  end
```

**Customer model:**

```rb
has_one     :address, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

A customer is created ok but not the address. Here's the form, for example:

```html
<form>
  <input name="customer[address][postal_address][street]" value="Foo Street" />
</form>
```

Logging "params", I see all the values but address is not creating. I believe the error lies in `shared_address_params`. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the customer model accept nested attributes for address?

Comment: Agree with @dbugger 
Also Sylar can you update your params in question

Comment: @dbugger, yes. I've updated the question.

Comment: @AnandBait What do you mean?

Comment: @Sylar I mean can you post the params that you are seeing on terminal so that we can check params and the nested attributes being passed.

Comment: @Sylar Also instead of selectively whitelisting nested attributes. *Just for debugging* 
1. can you permit all address attributes and check once? 
2. If point 1 works then stepwise whitelist nested attributes of address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just managed to lose yourself in layers of indirection and complexity in that parameters whitelist.

What you basically want is:

```
def customer_params
  params.require(:customer)
        .permit(
          address_attributes: {
            physical_address_attributes: [:street, :foo, :bar, :baz],
            postal_address: [:street, :foo, :bar, :baz]
          }
        )
end
```

As you can see here you need the param key `customer[address_attributes]` not just `customer[address]`.

Now lets refactor to cut the duplication:

```
def customer_params
  params.require(:customer)
        .permit(
          address_attributes: {
            physical_address_attributes: address_attributes,
            postal_address: address_attributes
          }
        )
end

def address_attributes
  [:street, :foo, :bar, :baz]
end
```

As you can see there should be very little added complexity here any and if you need to make it more flexible add arguments to the `address_attributes` method - after all building the whitelist is just simple array and hash manipulation.

If you want to handle mapping some sort of shared attributes to the two address types you really should do it in the model instead of bloating the controller with business logic. Like for example by creating setters and getters for a "virtual attribute":

```
class Address < ApplicationController
  def shared_address_attributes
    post_address_attributes.slice("street", "foo", "bar", "baz")
  end

  def shared_address_attributes=(**attrs)
    # @todo map the attributes to the postal and
    # visiting address
  end
end
```

That way you would just setup the form and whitelist it like any other attribute and the controller doesn't need to be concerned with the nitty gritty details.

```
def customer_params
  params.require(:customer)
        .permit(
          address_attributes: {
            shared_address_attributes: address_attributes,
            physical_address_attributes: address_attributes,
            postal_address: address_attributes
          }
        )
end
```